# Do action based on parameters received

Tags: python

I am writing an api that accepts two parameters "a" & "b". After receiving the parameters, it checks if their existence and do some actions based on which parameters have received. Here is some psudo code.

```
args = get.parameters

if "a" in args:
    print "x" # execute "x"
if "b" in args:
    print "y" # execute "y"
if both exists:
    print "x" # execute "x"
```

What will be the best way to do that?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what the possible conditions are. If `"b" in args`, must `print "y"` always be executed, or only if `"a" not in args`?

Comment: @larsmans Possible conditions are. I will either recieve "a" or "b" or it can be both. But If only "a" is recieved then execute some action lets say "x" and if only "b" is received, then do some action "y" but if both are received then do the same action that will be done if only "a" was received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acting on the requirement spelled out in the comment, this is what I would do:

```
if "a" in args:
    print "x"
elif "b" in args:
    print "y"
else:
    raise ValueError("must specify at least a or b")
```

There's no point in doing an `"a" in args and "b" in args` check, since the action to be taken is the same as for the case where you only have `"a"`. Note the `elif`, which makes sure the second check is only performed if the first fails.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited info you have provided, I would first check the existence of both `a` and `b` first. then presence of either `a` not `b` or `b` not `a`. That way you dont miss any conditions.

```
if 'a' in args and 'b' in args:
    print "x" # execute "x"
elif "a" in args:
    print "x" # execute "x"
elif "b" in args:
    print "y" # execute "y"
else:
    print 'ERROR need "a" or "b"'
```

Also I dont understand why not use `if-elif-else` rather than multiple `ifs`. These should be either-or conditions.

Comment: The conditions after the `and`s on the `elif`s are kinda redundant, you *already* checked if they both existed, why would you need to check *again* in every condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
args = sys.argv;
if len(args) > 1:
    args = args[1:]
    if "a" in args and "b" in args: print "x"
    elif "a" in args: print "x"
    elif "b" in args: print "y"
```